# Odoo 10 Web Service API: Workflow transition is not working

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Odoo version 10

I want to confirm sales order as soon as it gets created. For that, I'm trying below ruby command in irb but it always returns false and does not do any transition.

irb(main):119:0> models.exec_workflow('admin', 1, '12345678', 'sale.order', 'confirm', 20)

=> false

I'm using the administrator user only which has all rights. I'm able to confirm the order using odoo web wizard.

Answer (score 0):

you use the wrong command.

correct command is "order_confirm".

```
models.exec_workflow('DbName', 'userId', 'Password', 'sale.order', 'order_confirm',orderId)
```

Answer (score 0):

In odoo 10 there are no workflows to confirm customer orders. Thats why the function is returning False.

You should use the method action_confirm instead:

Sample code

```
so = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
  'sale.order', 'search',
   [[['name', '=', 'SO004']]])

print so

print models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'sale.order', 'action_confirm', so)
```

This will return True and sucessfully create a Sales Order from the Quotation.